# Android Ripple effect lags inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, material-design, ripple

Am using the sliding navbar with `appcompat-v7:22.+` that switches some fragments.

When I use a `Button` or `Cardview` inside an `Activity`, the ripple effect works well.

But If I use it inside the fragments, the ripple effect is slow and laggy.

Not sure what causes this....any help is appreciated. Cheers.

FYI: `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what caused this....may be due to improper gradle build.
Updating the dependencies to latest versions and rebuilding the entire project sorted all the problems. Cool.